# Django response - if POST = None leave blank key, value pair from jsonresponse

Tags: python, json, django

the below form + view works fine

forms.py

```
class FormGlobalSettings(forms.Form):
global_font_family = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, label='Font Family', choices=choices_font_family, empty_value=None)
```

views.py

```
def main_view(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form_global_settings = FormGlobalSettings()
    else:
    form_global_settings = FormGlobalSettings(data=request.POST)

    if all([form_global_settings.is_valid()]):
        cleaned_data = form_global_settings.cleaned_data

        nested_data = {"fontFamily": cleaned_data3['global_font_family']}

        return JsonResponse(nested_data)

    return render(request, 'pbi_theme_app/index.html', {'form_global_settings': form_global_settings})
```

Output is:

```
{"fontFamily": "Arial"}
```

However, what I am trying to achieve is, that sometimes the POST request is blank/empty/null, as the user doesn't want to have any value in this field. The choices for the global_font_family are set up in this manner:

```
choices_font_family = [(None, ""), ("Arial", "Arial"), etc..]
```

Meaning that the if the user leaves the field empty, it results into None. This results into having it in the json as null:

```
{"fontFamily": null}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve, and because I have hardcoded "fontFamily" into the jsonresponse, I want the whole key, value pair to be gone if the user decides to have the field empty, meaning that the whole key, value pair **"fontFamily: null** is gone from the jsonresponse.

To summarize: I need to somehow make the key in the json dynamic, and when the POST request is empty, I want to leave the whole key, value pair from getting inputed into the json.

The intended behaviour is seen on the following webpage, when you download the theme and you didnt input anything it leaves the whole json code empty:

https://powerbi.tips/tools/report-theme-generator-v3/

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to include `none` in the choice list. You can simply declare `null=True` in your `model.py` class fields.

You can achieve the intended behavior by overwriting the intended field in your `model.py` class before saving the input

let assume I have the following class.

```
choices_font_family = [
    ("c1", "choice1"),
    ("c2", "choice2"),
    ("c3", "choice3"),
    ("c4", "choice4")
]
class Post(models.Model):
    theme_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="some text", choices=choices_font_family )
    ....
    ....

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if theme_type is None:
            theme_type = '<some font>' # overwriting none to whatever you want it to be
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

## EDIT

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import FormGlobalSettings


class UserdataModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormGlobalSettings

    def clean(self):
        return self.clean()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(UserdataModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

> models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 choices_font_family = [
        ("c1", "choice1"),
        ("c2", "choice2"),
        ("c3", "choice3"),
        ("c4", "choice4")
    ]
class FormGlobalSettings(models.Model):
    theme_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="some text", choices=choices_font_family )
        ....
        ....
    
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if theme_type is None:
            theme_type = '<some font>' # overwriting none to whatever you want it to be
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is a link to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/) on saving and overwriting save. And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) is an example from Django docs on how to use forms and models.

If this solves your problem don't forget to accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I am not using any model, my model.py is empty, I am running everything only in forms and views. Bcs of that I dont fully understand where should I implement that "save" function, and how to call it?

Comment: i'll modify my answer now

Comment: thank you again, but as I've said, I am not using models at all, and I dont want to use them as they caused me some issues. I am using only forms and views. Thus I am not saving anything, in forms using only forms.Form, just as in the post that I've sent.

Comment: So I've been trying to implement your solution, however it does exactly the same thing as I've had programmed before. models.Model dont have save() method, only ModelForm does it seems. So I dont understand what we are trying to save. Plus that (if theme_type is None:
            theme_type = '<some font>') isnt doing anything, I want the theme_type to be be deleted (the whole key, value pair) if its None.

Comment: So we save the font family to be equal to the default font value if no font family is supplied.  So what you want to do is if the user does not choose a font you overwrite the default font with the same font. so basically if you have a variable `theme_type` that holds the font family, you want to say `theme_type  = default_font_family if font_family None else whatever the font family is given` Which i have shown how to use above. see this [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save] on overriding save